# NativeScript audio player in background mode

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Is it possible in Native Script to make an audio player in the background and with controllers on the lock screen?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but there are no plugins that do this currently. You will have to deal with the native side of this on both ios and Android. 

iOS is the easier one to implement, Android is quite complicated due to the backwards compatibility.